# Separate paragraph from large text in ansible playbook using regular expression

Tags: regex, ansible

I have following text.

```
****************
* 192.168.1.1
****************
mount | grep 'on /mnt/'
/dev/drbd1 on /mnt/export/SDL-upload-A type ext4 (rw)
/dev/drbd2 on /mnt/export/SDL-upload-B type ext4 (rw)
/devmapper/NIB_VG1-LV_ems_data on /mnt/export/ems_data type xfs 
[root ems_data]#
****************
* 192.168.1.4
****************
mount | grep 'on /mnt/'
nib-vip:/mnt/export/ems_data on /mnt/import/ems_data type nfs 
nib-vip:/mnt/export/SDL on /mnt/import/SDL type nfs 
[root ems_data]#
```

I want to separate the text as follow:

part1:

```
****************
* 192.168.1.1
****************
mount | grep 'on /mnt/'
/dev/drbd1 on /mnt/export/SDL-upload-A type ext4 (rw)
/dev/drbd2 on /mnt/export/SDL-upload-B type ext4 (rw)
/devmapper/NIB_VG1-LV_ems_data on /mnt/export/ems_data type xfs 
[root ems_data]#
```

part 2:

```
****************
* 192.168.1.4
****************
mount | grep 'on /mnt/'
nib-vip:/mnt/export/ems_data on /mnt/import/ems_data type nfs 
nib-vip:/mnt/export/SDL on /mnt/import/SDL type nfs 
[root ems_data]#
```

using regular expression and put it in a variable in ansible playbook.It will be greatly helpful if anyone give me any hints.I have tried `(?<=192.168.1.1)(*)(?=\#)` but it is not working.

my procedure:
1.I am taking the full text in register
2.and then using filter and the regular expression I am trying to separate it.

```
- name: read mount log
shell:  cat /var/tmp/diskmount.log
register: result_mount
- set_fact
   paragraph:"{{ result_mount.stdout | regex_search(regex) }}"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: it returns empty string.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my comment because it was not right. Try [`^\**[\s\S]*?^\[root ems_data\]#`](https://regex101.com/r/86n0R2/1)

Comment: I am afraid still the same result.It's returning empty string .

Comment: Can you add to your question how you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're trying to do it this way? I'm not sure regex is a good fit here. How about something like this?

```
shell: sed -n '/192.168.1.1/,/192.168.1.4/p' text.txt
```

Comment: I am working taking the log in register so can't use shell.